# Compiling with Xamarin Studio for Linux or Mac

Tags: linux, macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin-studio

Good morning. I just switched from Visual Studio to Xamarin Studio. I really like the interface and the multiplatform support but I have a question.

I already published an application but these are the files:

```
OpenTK.dll
AppTest.exe
OpenTK.xml
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcMIL.png (image)

I was expecting multiplatform compiling in this .NET Console Application but I just got windows executables.

I want to compile my game to Windows, Linux, and Mac (without needing java) but do I need a Linux partition or Virtual box to compile for Linux and the same for Mac (at least I have one of those)

Thanks.

Comment: you can run .NET exe's on Linux using Mono

Comment: The IDE does not matter much, https://blog.lextudio.com/status-of-monodevelop-xamarin-studio-253da80d022c You probably should stick to Visual Studio on Windows or Mac. If your goal is to develop a cross platform game, you'd better use something like MonoGame or Unity for simplicity. Console application based games might work (use `mono AppTest.exe` after you install Mono), but you would need to port your game anyway, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-portability/

Comment: Jason, i would like to completely port my game and people should not need extra programs

Comment: Voting to close : "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.". Please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs.Tnx

Comment: ***Might*** be more appropriate on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com , but be sure to consult that areas help and rules. Good luck.